# Is there an online version of jayadratha-yAmala?

Tags: scripture, tantra, book-recommendation

One of the category of tantric texts are the yAmala.granthas.

Is there an online.version of jayadrathayamala tantra ?

Comment: If the answer is no how one is supposed to answer it? :O

Comment: BTW i also know about this Yamala. It's one of the 8 Yamalas (Yamalashtaka)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part 1 of Jayadratha Yamala is available in pdf. You need to create an account to look at the preview. (Clicking on below link takes you to pdf)

https://www.scribd.com/document/51868775/Jayadratha-Yamalam-Part-1-Ok

However it does not contain the coveted and elusive Bagalaamukhi sahasranamam.

Comment: it has only 4 pages ? how come ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiysYHerPThAhU48HMBHeE4DAIQFjABegQIABAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsanskritebooks.blogspot.com%2F2011%2F08%2Fblog-post_30.html&usg=AOvVaw1I1Msr8ZX0qFekMDwOUhVZ

Comment: excellent ... very rare book. great contribution